# CodeIgniter session available in one controller but not in other

Tags: php, codeigniter

CodeIgniter session available in one controller but not in other...

Session is setting user controller

```
class User extends CI_Controller {
    // SEssion worked here 
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        session_start();
    }

function setSess (){
       // database model call, Value comes from database
       $_SESSION['user'] = array ( 'isLoggedIn' => true,
        'id' => $userData[0]['id'],
        'username' => 'ABC',
        'email_address' => $userData[0]['email_address'],
         'country' => $userData[0]['country'],
        'lastLoggedin' => $lastLoginTime
                                            );
  // Redirect to profile
}
}
```

Unable to receive it in

```
class Profile extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            session_start();
        }

        public function index() {}

        public function display() {
            ECHO "<PRE>";
            print_r($_SESSION);

            $data['title'] = 'Profile of '.$_SESSION['user']['username'];
            // Gives error here while echoing $_SESSION['user']['username']

        }
    }
```

What am i missing here? Any suggestion?

Comment: i am using it on local machine http://localhost/myproject. i am setting session under http://localhost

Comment: You're not missing a thing. This should work fine. Are you unsetting the session anywhere? This is the only thing I could think of.

Comment: Nope.. I am destroying session only on logout event.

Comment: Do any other super-globals behave the same or is it just the session?

Comment: It is pure core PHP $_SESSION.  I am not using any CodeIgniter Session library

Comment: I am not able to trace what is wrong....:-0

Comment: look there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449118/codeigniter-session-data-not-available-in-other-pages-after-login?rq=1

Comment: I cannot user CodeIgniter library. I have to keep long text in session. Codeigniter session has limitations over length of session data. It discards text sometimes if limitation exceeds

Comment: This should work.but not sure why not working. you can try to write `session_start();` at CI main `index.php`

Answer (score 0):

Do not use session_start(), instead, load CodeIgniter session library

In User Controller:

```
class User extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        if(!isset($this->session)) {
            $this->load->library('session'); # do not use 'session_start();'
        }
    }
    function setSess (){
       $_SESSION['user'] = array ( 'isLoggedIn' => true,
           'id' => $userData[0]['id'],
           'username' => 'ABC',
           'email_address' => $userData[0]['email_address'],
           'country' => $userData[0]['country'],
           'lastLoggedin' => $lastLoginTime
       );
    }
    ...
}
```

In Profile Controller:

```
class Profile extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        if(!isset($this->session)) {
            $this->load->library('session');
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Also make sure your config file is setup correctly. Follow documentation here [CodeIgniter Sessions](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#session-preferences)